# Django/React Native/OAuth: Best way to handle Auth flow?

Tags: django, react-native, oauth

So I'm trying to integrate a Django/Python backend framework with a React Native frontend, and I was wondering if there are any good resources/answers out there to handle OAuth flow?

I've tried a lot of different aspects, and from the server side at least, the best thing that possibly worked is `OAuth Toolkit`. I also want to use Django REST framework to exchange data between server/client.

However, I am confused about the flow of authentication between the app and the server and would appreciate a better understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Django OAuth Toolkit documentation has a good tutorial on how to get started:

[OAuth Toolkit Tutorial](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html)

A basic summary of the authentication flow:

- Login with credentials (Post request to server with username/password)
- Server returns an auth token to React-Native client application to use. You should store this somehow in the react-native app, such as a cookie
- When performing an API request, provide the token in the request header like so:

  - Authorization: "Bearer TOKEN_VALUE_RETURNED_FROM_SERVER"

Comment: What about going from client side to server side?

Comment: Could you elaborate?